# PC not booting even after changing the motherboard and processor

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

3 months ago, I accidentally bent my CPU socket pins as I was foolishly cleaning the mobo (socket 1155 Motherboard). Then after researching, I tried to correct the pins but no luck.
I put all the components and the PC didn't boot at all.
I tried, for like, 30-40 times but PC didn't boot with the bent pins. (Note that 1-2 pins also broke)
So I gave up for some months when I came to know that I will have to replace my Motherboard.

Now some weeks ago I bought a new Motherboard (Lapcare H61 socket 1155) and assembled the PC. The PC booted up normally and I installed the mobo drivers successfully.
Everything was going fine but the PC suddenly turned off (after 30 mins) and never booted again. I tried literally a 100 times in a week but PC didn't boot.
What used to happen:
After pressing the Power button, the CPU fan would try to spin but fail and PSU fan also stops spinning (all this used to happen in 1 second)
Monitor used to show Cable not connected.

Now I thought that during all this, my processor might have been damaged, so I bought a Core i3-3240.
I assembled the PC again today and it again booted up pretty fine. I was happy. The PC detected the new CPU and everything was just fine. I even restarted the PC and that was successful.
But again it turned off on its own after like 25-30 mins.
When I'm trying to turn it on, the CPU fan tries to spin but nothing happens (the same thing I explained above).

I have checked my RAM, HDD and they are fine (according to elimination method)
PC won't boot even after removing RAM and HDD and Optical Drive.
I have also checked the PSU using the Green-Black wire shorting technique and the PSU works fine (the fan spins just fine)
Please tell me what could be the issue, I'm depressed since months as I'm not financially strong. It's been hell for me all this time :(

Motherboard: Lapcare H61 Lga 1155
CPU: earlier Pentium G2020 and now Core i3-3240 3.40 GHz
RAM: 2 GB + 8 GB DDR3 HyperX
And yes, there's no thermal paste between my cpu and heatsink (intel stock) but this was the case since 1 year and PC used to work fine)
Edit: i have tried resetting CMOS but no luck
Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: I am surprised it would run for 30 minutes without proper thermal paste. Reinstall the CPU with proper thermal paste and test again.

Comment: To make things simpler, you can unplug your hard drive,  and optical drive. . A computer can start and stay on without them.  And of course don't need an optical drive connected.  Also your title says you changed MBRD and Processor, but doesn't mention if you change the PSU.  The "green-black wire shorting" method is perhaps not a sufficient test for PSU, if it passes it just means the PSU isn't completely dead but is possible PSU may be funny.

Comment: If it had only turned on for a few seconds then off, then (reminds me of some years back when another cable needed to plug in there).. But for your case that's not it.. Your case it runs for 25min then turns off, and then perhaps doesn't turn on...    If you wait half an hour does it turn on?  If so, it could be an overheading issue.  If it doesn't boot at all then maybe a bad PSU killed the MBRD. Really you should change PSU.  Also try a green-black test for eg 1hr.see if it stays on for 1hr.(albeit with no load)

Comment: If you're not using thermal paste, it's possible you killed the CPUs with overheating, not all CPUs will thermal throttle to protect themselves. Try the CPUs on a different motherboard if possible.

Comment: @John I have been using this PC without thermal paste since 1-2 year. Only after this incident, PC won't boot. Also, thermal paste ensures better heat transfer, but if the CPU isn't even processing and starting, what's the use of paste? I might be wrong but PC's do boot w/o paste. In my case, it is not even booting

Comment: @barlop yeah, I'm just booting with ATX 24 pin, CPU 4 pin connector, CPU, CPU fan and sometimes the 2 GB ram stick. For PSU, I will try another PSU in some days (will probably go at a repair shop). Thank you :)

Comment: @barlop The CPU isn't even a bit warm. I have waited half an hour to 10 hours to days but it won't work. And yeah, it doesn't "run for 25 mins and then turn off" rather "it just worked for 25 mins once and then turned off and never booted again, no matter how many hours I've waited" :( and the green black test is successful for 1 hour, the PSU fans are still running and it's been 1 hour :(

Comment: @VividKraig but I have been using it w/o thermal paste since 1-2 year, even used to play 15 GB games, but the CPU didn't get killed before :(

Comment: @RajatKhanduri still is possible that the PSU is bad, and it's possible that the PSU destroyed the MBRD. And it's possible that the PSU is bad but the motherboard is fine. And it's possible the CPU has an issue(don't make assumptions about things being fine and not thinking they need testing).  A repair shop is PERFECT for diagnosing this 'cos they have parts and can do these tests really fast maybe for a small fee. Even while you wait. Swapping PSU, swapping CPU. Thus indicating what part is faulty.

Comment: I think it's very clear that your CPUs are dead. So yes, perhaps it is your power supply, perhaps it is your lack of thermal paste, perhaps it is both. If your PSU is providing too much current, the CPU would heat up more than before, and the lack of thermal paste would prevent the dissipation of this excess heat. Regardless, the best course of action is to consult a professional. You've killed 2 CPUs, and it's likely the case that someone would need to physically examine the components to find the problem. Consult a professional, then answer your own question with their diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

It is finally fixed.
And the culprit was the SMPS/PSU.
Even though the Green-Black wire shorting method worked fine but the PSU was bad. The test wasn't sufficient as highlighted by @barlop.
I replaced that with a Zebronics 450W PSU and things are working well.
My mistake costed me 43 USD for a Mobo, 30 USD for an i3 3240 (tho I think I should return this as the culprit was PSU not my old Pentium) and 9 USD PSU.
Thanks everyone for their time.